# Silverlight Byte[] to its original file format

Tags: silverlight-4.0, arrays

is there a way to convert byte[] to its original file format?

```
Byte[] tempByte = new Byte[content.Length];
tempByte = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
```

Comment: what is the "original file format"?

Comment: any file format. the client is blinded with its original format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Base64 encoded string, then yes Convert.FromBase64String will give you back a byte array identical to the one that was converted *to* a Base64 string.

However, your first line is unnecessary. You are allocating an array equal to the length of content which just gets overwritten by the return value from Convert.FromBase64String.

```
byte[] tempByte = Convert.FromBase64String(content);

File.WriteAllBytes(path, tempByte);
```

Answer (score 0):

The byte array should already be having what you originally read from the file. Write the byte array to a file on the disk and you should be good to go!

Comment: Can you please illustrate on how to?